# Lienard-Wiechert Potential derivation in Wald's "Advanced Classical Electromagnetism"

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, special-relativity, differentiation, calculus

I want to follow the Lienard-Wiechert potential derivation in Robert Wald's E-M book, page 179. I do not understand $dX(t_\text{ret})/dt$ on the right side. I assume the chain rule is applied and $x'^i$ does depend on $t$.

$$ \frac{\partial[x'^i - X^i(t - |\mathbf x - \mathbf x'|/c)]}{\partial x'^j} = \delta^i{}_j - \frac{x^j - x'^j}{c|\mathbf x - \mathbf x'|} \frac{dX^i}{dt}(t_\text{ret}) $$

$$ t_\text{ret} = t - \frac 1c |\mathbf x - \mathbf x'| $$

Comment: See: https://www.mathjax.org/